# Show that $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\phi(x,y) = (x,x+y)$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\phi(x,y) = (x,x+y)$ is linear

I know that to be linear it must satisfy:

(i) $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$, and

(ii) $\phi(ax) = a\phi(x)$

But, how does one apply that to the given values above?

Comment: Better to use different notation; say $u=(x,y)$ and $v=(w,z)$ for elements of $\Bbb R^2$. Now show that $\phi(u+v)=\phi(u)+\phi(v)$, etc.

Comment: So, function of two variables to be bilinear, it should be linear with respect to each variable. So
\begin{align}
\phi(x_1 + x_2, y) &= \phi(x_1, y) + \phi(x_2, y) \\
\phi(x, y_1 + y_2) &= \phi(x, y_1) + \phi(x, y_2) \\
\phi(ax, y) &= a \phi (x, y) \\
\phi(x, ay) &= a \phi (x, y)
\end{align}
So, you just need to check if above holds for $\forall x, x_1, x_2,y, y_1 ,y_2, a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Kaster: The question explicitely asks for linearity and _not_ for bilinearity. Which makes sense, because the map is linear and not bilinear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2)$, and  let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align*}
 \phi(x+y)
 &= \phi((x_1,x_2) + (y_1,y_2))
 = \phi( (x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2) ) \\
 &= (x_1 + y_1, x_1 + y_1 + x_2 + y_2)
 = (x_1, x_1 + x_2) + (y_1, y_1 + y_2) \\
 &= \phi((x_1, x_2)) + \phi((y_1,y_2))
 = \phi(x) + \phi(y),
\end{align*}
which shows the first condition, as well as
\begin{align*}
 \phi(a x)
 &= \phi(a(x_1,x_2))
 = \phi((a x_1, a x_2))
 = (a x_1, a x_1 + a x_2) \\
 &= (a x_1, a (x_1 + x_2))
 = a (x_1, x_1 + x_2)
 = a \phi((x_1, x_2))
 = a \phi(x),
\end{align*}
which shows the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
&1 &0 \\
&1 &1
\end{pmatrix}$$
is a matrix $M$ such that multiplying by $M$ gives the same result as $\phi$. Multiplying vectors by a matrix is linear. $M$ is the matrix of $\phi$.

Comment: Downvoter: What, It's wrong? and an answer that's the same doesn't receive the same abuse? Sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

$\phi: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is linear if and only if it is represented by a matrix. In fact in this case we have

$\phi(x,y)=$
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
1 & 1  \end{array} \right) $
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x  \\
y  \end{array} \right) $
$= (x,x+y)$.